# How can I get a command to run before login (ie while booting or just after)?

Tags: boot, command-line, startup, brightness

I have an encrypted home folder, so I can't log in automatically (and I wouldn't want to) but also my display defaults to the minimum brightness at each boot. To fix this I run the command

```
`xbacklight =100`
```

as a startup application, but this only runs when I log in and not when a guest logs in or for the login screen which is beautiful, but not seen.

A fix for the whole issue would be preferred, or just a way to run commands during the boot process. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and append the line

```
display-setup-script=/usr/local/sbin/lightdm-setup.sh
```

to the `[SeatDefaults]` section. Then create the file `/usr/local/sbin/lightdm-setup.sh` with this content:

```
#! /bin/sh
xbacklight =100
```

And make the file executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/lightdm-setup.sh`). After a reboot or when you restart lightdm (`sudo restart lightdm`) your script should run.

Comment: i get low graphics screen when i boot my system after running the said commands on 12.04 32-bit

Comment: I have no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file. Is there somewhere template for it?

Comment: Maybe you are using gdm instead of lightdm? Then [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450835/how-to-execute-command-before-user-login-on-linux) might help you.